# Django: User.object.get() logs user in

Tags: django, django-views

I am just a beginner in Django but I have come across very interesting problem. I am not logged in on my webpage, but after I want to see someone's profile it automatically logs me in that user. It seems like a huge security hole. I also put print statement in and it says that user is authenticated.
Answers will be appreciated.

views.py

```
def login_view(request):

    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
    return render(request, "home/login.html", {'form': form})

def user_feedView(request, username):
     try:
         userU = User.objects.get(username=username)
         print(userU.is_authenticated)
     except User.DoesNotExist:
         raise Http404("User does not exist")


    return render(request, 'home/user_feed.html', {'user': userU})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('user/<username>/', views.user_feedView, name='username'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('login/', views.login_view, name='login'),
    path('', views.index, name='home')
]
```

Comment: Does `print(userU.is_authenticated)` print `is authenticated` for any user  ? if you are login in and you test it with your own username, actually it will show you as connected.

Comment: @Lemayzeur Yes, it does.

Comment: @Lemayzeur that is irrelevent; `is_authenticated` always returns True for any user object.

Comment: `is_authenticated` is a function, so use (). `userU.is_authenticated()`

Comment: change your url names, do not use names that django already uses, such as `logout` `username`

Comment: @DanielRoseman But it says, that bool object is not callable. This is also the reason why I used without ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't "log you in" as that user. You pass an object called "user" to the template, which overrides any other object with that name. But this is just a display issue; you are not authenticated as that user.

You could probably just choose a different name for your template object.

Comment: I know that, but the problem is that I have in navbar name of the current user. But when I come to this page, the name of AnonymousUser changes in username of userU.

Comment: All I want to do is to show profile of user that I type in url section.

Comment: Yes, which is exactly why I suggested using a different name for the template object.

Comment: Okay, I see. I just didn't know, that one variable in template can interfere with other template. Because this template is for user feed and it is in app subdirectory, while navbar is in webpage main directory in base.html. Why can variable in subdirectory change value in main directory? I hope that is clear what am I asking. Thanks!